# 301 Redirect forum and all posts to homepage

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to redirect my /forum/ page and all subsequent forum posts (e.g. /forum/topic/3335/) to myhomepage.com.

I've tried all the possible ways I've seen on SO but none of them will do it and completely strip the query string.

What is the best way to 301 all of these posts to my home page, and completely strip the query string (including the trailing ? that I don't want).

Thanks!

Edit:

```
redirectMatch 301 ^/forum/ http://www.newsite.com/?
```

This redirected them all to my homepage, but kept the ?, which I don't want.

```
RewriteEngine on RewriteRule ^/forum/(.*) http://www.newsite.com/? [L,R=301]
```

This just didn't work at all.  It didn't redirect anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way would be [`RedirectMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch):

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/forum/.*$ http://myhomepage.com
```

**Note:** If *forum* is under *myhomepage.com* you don't need to use the full domain, you could just use `/`.

#### UPDATE

To remove the query string, you'll need to use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/forum/.*$ http://myhomepage.com [L,R=301]
```

Comment: For some reason, the updated one doesn't work.  I've added it as-is to .htaccess and within <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> and neither performs a redirect.

Comment: Nevermind, turns out I was using a WordPress plugin that overrides the .htaccess RewriteEngine.  I added it into the plugin as a RegEx and it worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using .htaccess possibly, If we are thinking the same thing!